# How to handle char * from packed struct in cgo?

Tags: c++, c, go, struct, cgo

Since Go doesn’t support packed struct I found this great article explains everything with examples how to work with packed struct in go. https://medium.com/@liamkelly17/working-with-packed-c-structs-in-cgo-224a0a3b708b

The problem is when I try char * in place of [10]char it's not working. I'm not sure how this conversion works with [10]char and not with char * . Here is example code taken from above article and modified with char * .

```golang
package main

/*
#include "stdio.h"
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct{
    unsigned char a;
    char b;
    int c;
    unsigned int d;
    char *e; // changed from char[10] to char *
}packed;

void PrintPacked(packed p){
    printf("\nFrom C\na:%d\nb:%d\nc:%d\nd:%d\ne:%s\n", p.a, p.b, p.c, p.d, p.e);
}

*/
import "C"
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
)

//GoPack is the go version of the c packed structure
type GoPack struct {
    a uint8
    b int8
    c int32
    d uint32
    e [10]uint8
}

//Pack Produces a packed version of the go struct
func (g *GoPack) Pack(out *C.packed) {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, g)
    *out = *(*C.packed)(C.CBytes(buf.Bytes()))
}

func main() {
    pack := &GoPack{1, 2, 3, 4, [10]byte{}}
    copy(pack.e[:], "TEST123")
    cpack := C.packed{} //just to allocate the memory, still under GC control
    pack.Pack(&cpack)
    C.PrintPacked(cpack)
}
```

*I'm working with cgo first time so correct me if i am wrong at any point.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing ten (zero) bytes of `GoPack.e` into the `packed.e` which is of type `char *`. This won't work, because pointers will be 4 or 8 bytes depending on your system, so even if the bytes represented a valid pointer, you are overflowing the amount of memory allocated.

If you want to create a valid structure with a valid `packed.e` field, you need to allocate 10 bytes of memory in the C heap, copy the bytes into that, and then point `packed.e` to this allocated memory. (You will also need to free this memory when you free the corresponding `packed` structure). You can't do this directly with `binary.Write`.

You can take this as a starting point:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, g.a)
binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, g.b)
binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, g.c)
binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, g.d)
binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uintptr(C.CBytes(g.e))
*out = *(*C.packed)(C.CBytes(buf.Bytes()))
```

The function `C.CBytes(b)` allocates `len(b)` bytes in the C heap, and copies the bytes from `b` into it, returning an `unsafe.Pointer`.

Note that I've copied your `*out = *(*C.packed)...` line from your code. This actually causes a memory leak and an unnecessary copy. Probably it would be better to use a writer that writes bytes directly to the memory pointed to by `out`.

Perhaps this?

```
const N = 10000 // should be sizeof(*out) or larger
buf := bytes.NewBuffer((*[N]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(out))[:])
```

This makes a `bytes.Buffer` that directly writes to the `out` struct without going through any intermediate memory. Note that because of unsafe shenanigans, this is vulnerable to a buffer overflow if you write more bytes of data than is pointed to by `out`.

Words of warning: this is all pretty nasty, and prone to the same sorts of problems you'd find in C, and you'd need to check the cgo pointer rules to make sure that you're not vulnerable to garbage collection interactions. A point of advice: given that you say you "don't have much experience with pointers and memory allocation", you probably should avoid writing or including code like this because the problems it can introduce are nefarious and may not be immediately obvious.

Comment: Can you give an example ? It'll be helpful. I don't have much experience with pointers and memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. By hours of scretching my head, i somehow finally figured out my self the same you explained (storing pointer location instead char array).

Comment: Hey @AbhiBhalgami, would you be willing to share your final solution?

Comment: @Mike Yes as I said in a previous comment I figured out exactly the same as in the accepted answer. I stored pointer location and later on cgo will able access that by going to that location